# 'Multiply' string cells to form an MxN size cell array of combined strings

Tags: string, matlab, plot, colors, cell-array

I'm plotting a variable number of lines.

The number of lines is the product of two other numbers, so that (for example) for all the prefixes `A`, and all the suffixes `B`, I plot 
`['A(i)','B(j)']`.

I can set the linetype using strings `'-'`, `':'`,`'--'`,`'-.'` - I want to use these to separate out the lines by their index in `A`.

I can set the line colors using strings like `'g'`,`'b'`,`'r'`.

Setting these using a `switch` or `for` loop is not so hard.

Is it possible to 'multiply' two cells to form a string/cell holding the full string/cell needed to specify all line types?

If I have

```
lineType = {'-',':','--','-.'};
lineColor = {'g','b','r'};
```

how can I get

```
lineString = {'g-','g:','g--','g-.',...
              'b-','b:','b--','b-.',...
              'r-','r:','r--','r-.'};
```

**Simple solution** (please let me know if there's a built-in, or better solution)

```
lineString = cell(sizeA*sizeB, 1);
idx = 1;
for i = 1:sizeA
    for j = 1:sizeB
         lineString{idx} = [A{i},B{j}];
         idx = idx + 1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and [`strcat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

```
[cc, tt] = ndgrid(1:numel(lineColor), 1:numel(lineType));
lineString = strcat(lineColor(cc), lineType(tt));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an alternative solution. Use `repmat` to eliminate the need for `for` loop and use `cellfun` to perform the joining of strings. You need to set `UniformOutput` in `cellfun` to false because the output is neither scalar cell array, scalar structure, nor scalar value.

```
lineType_ = repmat(lineType, size(lineColor,2), 1);
lineColor_ = repmat(lineColor', 1, size(lineType,2));
lineString = cellfun(@horzcat, lineColor_, lineType_, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Comment: you can use `cellfun(@horzcat,` to save one step.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! I've edited my answer accordingly.